# Using a third party link to send a user to download a file in a question

Tags: discussion

Take this question:
[Is there a way to export multiple groups within a PSD into individual PSDs](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98396/is-there-a-way-to-export-multiple-groups-within-a-psd-into-individual-psds)

I looked into it a bit more because I felt it looked like a potential advertisment. Then noticed the first link goes through goo.gl and downloads a jsx file. I've never seen this in an answer before, and pondering if that could be used for malicious purposes. What is the stance of the community on these types of links?

Comment: This is slightly related. What about using a third party link that answers their question, that took a 2 second google search? Encouraging people to help themselves with common problems that are easily answered with an internet query would save a lot of trouble. It goes against my perceived mission of GDSE, to curate an index of fine questions and answers. It would teach people to be independent researchers and free up people on here to answer the tough questions.

Comment: Maybe a snarky tag like "easily found on internet" or "google worthy" would give the message and still allow thorough answers

Comment: @Webster While I agree that there is worth to teaching people to become more resourceful, someone's common problem can be another's exceptional problem. The other problem is that it's not because an answer can be found somewhere else online that the knowledge will be effectively preserved in the long term. The chances of this happening on SE is increased because of the CC license. And finally, a snarky tag would go against the rule "Be nice." so I have to disagree overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) All links should be treated with caution.  I would suggest using a URL previewer that can be enabled in most browsers and when downloading anything from any question or answer is taken at the user's own risk.
2) The JSX file might be in relation to the script that runs in InDesign's JavaScript panel.

While it might seem some what alarming to post a shortened URL I would suggest commenting on the new users answer to request why he shortened it.  I would also go as far as to state it might be considered/flagged as spam since he is a new member.

If he has no further contribution after his Q&A in the next few months mods would likely take his whole purpose was to post spam and the mods might decide to nuke the Q&A all together.